# How to exclude a single file from project in PhpStorm so that it doesn't show in search?

Tags: phpstorm

I can exclude directories by right clicking on them and selecting "Mark directory as->excluded". After that I no longer see files from that directory in search results.

Can I do the same for a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with Right click | Mark as Plain Text.
Also, there's a possibility to exclude files by pattern in Settings | Directories, but in your case it may be less convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this [page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/excluding-files-from-project.html) it shows you the ways to achive the thing you want.

(It explains what [Eugene Morozov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522783/6439460) suggested)